# Estimate growth rates in a probit/logit model

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, logit, probit, growth-model

I consider a situation where k different kinds of bacteria grow together in a petri dish and each kind of bacteria exhibits exponential growth, i.e. the population size over time is given by $N_i(t) = N_i(0)e^{r_it}$ for each $i = 1,\dots, k$. All growth rates but the first are unknown, and $r_1 = 1$. At specified points in time $t = 0, 1, \dots, T$, I take a random sample from the petri dish of fixed size, say M. Now let $n_i(t)$ denote the number of bacteria of type i sampled at time t. Then $n_i(t)$ is a realization of a binomial random variable with parameters $(M,p_i)$ where $p_i = N_i(0)e^{r_it} /\sum_{j = 1}^k N_j(0)e^{r_jt}$.

My goal is to find a method to estimate the unknown growth rates $r_i$ based on the samples $\{ n_i(t) \}_{i,t}$. One way to do so is to compute the log ratios $\log(N_i(t)/N_1(t))$ and regress them on the time vector. This yields reasonable results but I feel it is conceptually wrong. On the other hand I could also compute a probit/logit regression but I don't know how to obtain the growth rates from the regression coefficients.

Sorry in case the format of the question is not fine. It's my first post here. Many thanks for any ideas!